# Doctrine oneToMany - querying for one

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relationship, one-to-many

I have a one to many relationship where one page has many versions.

```
**page**

id
parent_id

**page_version**
id
page_id
title
published
date
```

These are related by the foreign key page_id. So I have a Page entity and a PageVersion entity:

> ```
> class Page
> {
>     /**
>     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageVersion", mappedBy="page")
>     */
>    private $pageversions;
> }
> ```

```
class PageVersion
{
    /**
     * @var page
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="pageversions")
     *
     */
    private $page;

}
```

So I can get all page versions for each page. However, each page will only ever have one published page version. Therefore, when querying how can I get the latest version? I.e Where published = '1' rather than getting a list of all versions?

Here is an example of my query:

```
public function findAllPages()
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
        SELECT DISTINCT p,v
        FROM XYZWebsiteBundle:Page p
        JOIN p.pageversions v
        WHERE v.published = :published
        AND v.deleted = :deleted'
    )->setParameters(array('published' => 1, 'deleted' => 0));

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However if I loop through the result I can only access the Page properties and not PageVersion properties e.g title, published, date etc.

> $entities = $em->getRepository('XYZWebsiteBundle:Page')->findAllPages();

```
    foreach($entities as $entity){
        print($entity->getPageVersion()->getTitle());
    }
```

The error returned is Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::getTitle().

Answer (score 0):

```
$er = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XYZWebsiteBundle:Page');
$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.published = :published')
                ->setParameter('published', 1)
    ;

$entities=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

If you are sure there will never be no more than 1 page with the published status, you can even use getOneOrNullResult() instead of getResult(). This returns null if there is no matching entity, the entity if there is one matching, and an exception if there is more than one.

Edit: ok, so you have to build the query on PageVersion rather than page then. Try:

```
 $er = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XYZWebsiteBundle:PageVersion');
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.page = :page')
                    ->setParameter('page', $page)
        ->andWhere('p.published = :published')
                    ->setParameter('published', 1)
        ;

    $pageVersion=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

with $page being the page you are trying to find the published version for.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but got the following error:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 54 near 'published = ': Error: Class XYZ\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Page has no field or association named published

FYI The published field is within page_version rather than page so how do I reference this from the query?

Comment: Thanks. To give you more information, I have a list of pages in my CMS where an admin user can add/edit/delete etc. So if I had a listAction where I wanted to list all pages would I simply run a query to get all Page entities (as it doesn't matter about the version at this point), then when I wish to edit that page, within the editAction I would run your second query to get the latest version (where published = 1)? So then I can pull in the latest version data and edit it.

Comment: Actually I do need the latest version when querying for pages initially because I need to display the title of the page. Therefore, when querying for page entities I also need to get the latest page version so I can pull in the latest title within the list. Therefore, I need to query for pages but join page_version where published = 1 then I can loop though each page and pull out the latest title as well. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Before going further, could you please tell me if the second query I proposed worked?

Comment: Yes that works to get all page versions for one specific page. However, I'm also trying to get a list of all pages with the latest page version for each. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my original question now with the latest query I have tried.